# How to rotate CaLayer Vertically along x axis?

Tags: swift, calayer

I am trying to make a video transition related application. I have used `CABasicAnimation` to rotate a `CaLayer`. It gives me circular rotation. I want the rotation the `CaLayer` vertically along yhr X axis. What should I do?

```
let rotationAnimationx = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.x")

rotationAnimationx.fromValue = 0
rotationAnimationx.byValue = Double.pi * 2            
rotationAnimationx.duration = 3
rotationAnimationx.beginTime = CFTimeInterval(time[image])
rotationAnimationx.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
rotationAnimationx.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

blackLayer.add(rotationAnimationx, forKey: "transform.rotation.x")
```